# Quadratic equation within quadratic

Tags: quadratics

Edited version:-

If both roots of equation $$4x^2 -20px+(25p^2 +15p- 66)=0 $$ are less than $2$, find the value of $p$. How to solve such type of equations?

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

Rewrite as $(2x - 5p)^2 = 66 - 15p$, 
so that $2x - 5p = \pm \sqrt{66-15p}$.

Now you want $66 - 15p \gt 0$ and you want $x_1$ and $x_2$ to be less than 2.
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Another way would be to use the condition for both roots of a quadratic $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ to be less than 2 are (1) Discriminant positive, (2) $ 2 \gt \frac{-b}{2a}$ and (3) $af(2) \gt 0$ where $f$ is the quadratic

Comment: You can use `\pm` to get the symbol $\pm$ in front of the square root, if you like.

Comment: @String Thanks. Have edited accordingly.

Comment: I think he wants $p < 2$ for both $x_1, x_2$ and not $x_1, x_2 < 2$

Comment: There is certainly some ambiguity in the way the question is poorly stated...

Comment: Please will u solve further.

Comment: Also it's my first question here sorry for unclearness

Comment: Please send me a link by which I can understand the third alternative u stated above .

Comment: @Muzamil  See [here] (http://www.askiitians.com/iit-jee-algebra/quadratic-equations-and-expressions/interval-in-which-the-roots-lie.aspx), though this does not show a graph, does take all cases. Please accept answer once you are satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

The roots are $$\frac{1}{2} \left(5 p\pm\sqrt{3} \sqrt{22-5 p}\right)$$ where clearly the biggest root is $\frac{1}{2} \left(5 p+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{22-5 p}\right)$. Now if this root is smaller than $2$ the other root will also be smaller than $2$. 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \left(5 p+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{22-5 p}\right)&<2\\
5 p+\sqrt{3} \sqrt{22-5 p}&<4\\
\sqrt{3} \sqrt{22-5 p}&<4-5p\\
3 (22-5 p)&<(4-5p)^2\\
66-15 p&<16 - 40 p + 25 p^2\\
0&<-50 - 25 p + 25 p^2\\
0&<-2 -  p + p^2\\
0&<(p+1)(p-2)\\
\end{align}
If $p<-1$ or $p>2$ will the inequality hold ... (why?) Also note that $\sqrt{3} \sqrt{22-5 p}<4-5p$ requires $0<4-5p$ i.e. $p<\frac45$. Hence only $p<-1$ is acceptable. On the other hand we require $p<\frac{22}{5}$ hence $$p<-1.$$

Comment: Not true. Take p = 3. The equation is $4x^2 - 60x + (225+45-66) = 0$ which simplifies to $2x^2 - 30x + 102 = 0$ , where one root is almost near 10.

Comment: @Shailesh ($p<-1$ OR $p>2$) AND ($p<\frac{22}5$) is equivalent to ($p<-1$) OR ($2<p<\frac{22}5$).

Comment: I understand that, but when I take p = 3, I get one root which is greater than more than 2 which is not what the problem wants. So something has gone wrong somewhere

Comment: ups thanks for the comments. I just fixed the problem :-)

Comment: I'm not verifying it, but now I like your method better than the way I have written my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot all but can we square both sides of inequalty?

Comment: @Muzamil as long as you know the sign of both sides yeah, for example $-6<1$ but $(-6)^2>1$ ...